# Toggle box closed, as other opens?

Tags: jquery, toggle

Can someone help me out with this code, i assume its easy if you know how..?

Currently click to toggle box appears below.

I need it so when you click on the other toggle, the box currently open closes, so its basically impossible for them to be both open at the same time?

But you can still toggle each individual one open/closed as normal, just when its open the other one (if open) closes also.

So far.. http://jsfiddle.net/CkTRa/380/

Thank you.

UPDATE:

Can it work with targeting independent boxes like so...?

HTML:

```
<div>
<h3 class = "trigger"> <a href="#box1">Heading 1</a></h3> 
</div>
<div>
<h3 class = "trigger"><a href="#box2">Heading 2</a></h3>
</div>

<div class = "toggle" id="box1">
    box one content
</div>
<div class = "toggle" id="box2">
    box two content
</div>​
```

jQuery so far:

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".toggle").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this simple code should work perfectly

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(".trigger").not(this).next(".toggle").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).next(".toggle").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

[See jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CkTRa/395/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add a class to the opened one, and use that class target the opened 
one. For example, you could add a class `open` when you open it, and use the selector `.open` to close the opened one:

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $('.open').slideToggle('slow').toggleClass('open');       
    $(this).next(".toggle").toggleClass('open').slideToggle("slow");
 });
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/CkTRa/389/

Comment: This might not work completely as you intend it to. If the slide is open for one heading and you click that again, it will slide in and slide out again.

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution: When you click one you first close all (if any), then open the one you clicked:

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
  $(".trigger").next(".toggle").slideUp("slow");
  $(this).next(".toggle").slideDown("slow");
});
```

The only drawback is that if you click the open one again, you will close it and reopen it, but I'm not sure if that will be a problem with your functionality or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to this problem:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $('.trigger:not(.current)').next(".toggle").slideUp('slow');
    $(this).removeClass('current').next(".toggle").slideToggle("slow");
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paragnair/CkTRa/391/

**UPDATE:**
 The following example makes sure the heading you clicked slides only after other headings are slided up.

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    var currentTrigger = $(this);            
    currentTrigger.addClass('current');
    $('.trigger:not(.current)').next(".toggle").slideUp('slow', function(){
        currentTrigger.removeClass('current').next(".toggle").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paragnair/CkTRa/392/

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be:

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/tAqm5/)*

- You can have more than 2 headings.
- It toggles already opened ones
- It just closes the opened one if clicked again

jQuery:

```
$('.trigger').next('.toggle').hide();
$('.trigger').click(function() {
    var el = $(this).next('.toggle');
    var doit = el.is(':visible') ? el.slideUp() : ($('.toggle').slideUp()) (el.slideDown());
});
```